# Getting 304 error for an ajax call with using IE browser

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, internet-explorer

I wrote an ajax call but I have a problem with IE web browser because in Chrome, `ajaxFunction(1)` is working properly (it gets `200 OK` on network section of my browser while I am browsering). On the other hand same page with same actions with using IE, function returns `304 error`. I tried manually (`call.php?which=1`) with using IE, it is working. I could not find what is the problem in this case?

PS. My codes are working in manual. I want to know what is my problem with IE browser. Which codes run different in browsers?

Here is some codes:

```
function ajaxFunction(a)
{
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET","call.php?which="+a,true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
```

Apart from that,

```
/* in call.php after connection codes */
$came = $_GET['which'];
mysql_query("UPDATE ...");
```

**Updates**

I am using IE 9.0 (update version 9.0.10)

Also I added this code to call.php

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

**Answer**

After using cache-control and cache cleaning of browser it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the root cause - and possible solutions - are addressed by these links:

- [Resolve HTTP 304 - not modified in AJAX call made via GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475886/resolve-http-304-not-modified-in-ajax-call-made-via-gwt)
- [jQuery AJAX producing 304 responses when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502002/jquery-ajax-producing-304-responses-when-it-shouldnt)
- https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/

Apparently, IE "aggressively caches ajax requests".  The above links should help you work around the problem.

PS:

What version of IE is experiencing this problem?

Comment: I tried some ways to solve with that way- see updates in the question.